# JSON to Java Object get property to compare

Tags: java, json, list

After using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create POJO class to convert JSON to Java Object I'm trying to get property of "distance" "inMeters" to compare them  but I can't get them because it is List is there any way I can compare them

```
   {
 "originAddresses": [
 "58 Oxford St, Fitzrovia, London W1D 1BH, UK"
],
 "destinationAddresses": [
  "109 Marylebone High St, Marylebone, London W1U 4RX, UK",
  "143 Great Titchfield St, Fitzrovia, London W1W, UK",
"210 Great Portland St, Fitzrovia, London W1W 5BQ, UK",
"43-51 Great Titchfield St, Fitzrovia, London W1W 7PQ, UK"
],
"rows": [
  {
    "elements": [
    {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "inSeconds": 457,
        "humanReadable": "8 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "inMeters": 1662,
        "humanReadable": "1.7 km"
      }
    },
    {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "inSeconds": 383,
        "humanReadable": "6 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "inMeters": 1299,
        "humanReadable": "1.3 km"
      }
    },
    {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "inSeconds": 376,
        "humanReadable": "6 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "inMeters": 1352,
        "humanReadable": "1.4 km"
      }
    },
    {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "inSeconds": 366,
        "humanReadable": "6 mins"
      },
      "distance": {
        "inMeters": 932,
        "humanReadable": "0.9 km"
      }
    }
  ]
  }
 ]
 }
```

This is my Main POJO Class  in the compareTo class it require int but it show only List :

```
package com.example;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class LocationGoogle implements Comparable<LocationGoogle> {
public LocationGoogle(String originAddress, String destinationAddress,Row 
rows){
    super();
    this.destinationAddresses = destinationAddresses;
    this.originAddresses = originAddresses;
    this.rows= (List<Row>) rows;
}

@SerializedName("originAddresses")
@Expose
private List<String> originAddresses = null;
@SerializedName("destinationAddresses")
@Expose
private List<String> destinationAddresses = null;
@SerializedName("rows")
@Expose
private List<Row> rows = null;

public List<String> getOriginAddresses(){
    return originAddresses;
}

public void setOriginAddresses(List<String> originAddresses){
    this.originAddresses = originAddresses;
}

public List<String> getDestinationAddresses(){
    return destinationAddresses;
}

public void setDestinationAddresses(List<String> destinationAddresses){
    this.destinationAddresses = destinationAddresses;
}

public List<Row> getRows(){
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(List<Row> rows){
    this.rows = rows;
}



@Override
public int compareTo(LocationGoogle compareTime){
    int compare =((LocationGoogle)compareTime).getRows();
    return 0;
  }
 }
```

Is JSON to Java Object is good or bad way to convert JSON to java data. Should I keep doing this or find another way?

This is class Row :
    package com.example;

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Row {

    @SerializedName("elements")
    @Expose
    private List<Element> elements = null;

    public List<Element> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(List<Element> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.valueOf(elements);

    }

}
```

This is Elements class:

```
package com.example;
  import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

   public class Element {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("duration")
@Expose
private Duration duration;
@SerializedName("distance")
@Expose
private Distance distance;

@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.valueOf(distance);
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Duration getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

public Distance getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(Distance distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

 }
```

This is Duration class:

```
     package com.example;
  import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

 public class Duration {

@SerializedName("inSeconds")
@Expose
private Integer inSeconds;
@SerializedName("humanReadable")
@Expose
private String humanReadable;

public Integer getInSeconds() {
    return inSeconds;
}

public void setInSeconds(Integer inSeconds) {
    this.inSeconds = inSeconds;
}

public String getHumanReadable() {
    return humanReadable;
}

public void setHumanReadable(String humanReadable) {
    this.humanReadable = humanReadable;
}

@Override
public String toString (){

    return String.valueOf(inSeconds);
}

}
```

This is Distance class:

```
      package com.example;
  import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
   import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

  public class Distance implements Comparable{

@SerializedName("inMeters")
@Expose
private Integer inMeters;
@SerializedName("humanReadable")
@Expose
private String humanReadable;

public Integer getInMeters() {
    return inMeters;
}

public void setInMeters(Integer inMeters) {
    this.inMeters = inMeters;
}

public String getHumanReadable() {
    return humanReadable;
}

public void setHumanReadable(String humanReadable) {
    this.humanReadable = humanReadable;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.valueOf(inMeters);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o){
    int compare = ((Distance)o).getInMeters();
    return  compare-this.inMeters;

}
}
```

The code i using  to compare them:

```
    @Override
public int compareTo(LocationGoogle compareTime){
    String i= getRows()
    int compare =((LocationGoogle)compareTime).getRows();
    return 0;
}
```

After seeing required int but  have List i confusing.

Comment: Show us the code of the class `Row`.

Comment: sure i have edit it as you can see in the the json it need to go thourgh rows then elements then it go to duration and distance actully i just need distance to compare it to get the closest

Comment: Nice try :) Now add `Element` and all classes nested until we reach `inSeconds`. Please also include the code you use to compare these.

Comment: This is code i using to compare:  
 @Override
    public int compareTo(LocationGoogle compareTime){
      
        int compare =((LocationGoogle)compareTime).getRows();
        return 0;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("Path to json file");
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
        System.out.println("json object = "+json.toString());

        JSONArray result = (JSONArray) json.get("rows");
        JSONObject result1 = (JSONObject)result.get(0);
        JSONArray elements = (JSONArray) result1.get("elements");
        JSONObject result2 = (JSONObject)elements.get(0);
        JSONObject distance = (JSONObject)result2.get("distance");
        JSONObject duration = (JSONObject)result2.get("duration");
        Distance=(String)distance.get("inMeters");
```

use json_simple-1.0.2.jar file. It is step by step extraction.